# Regex Expression Capture Multi Words In A Column

Tags: .net, regex, expression

Goal: I'm struggling with an expression (.NET) that can capture just the Full **Description Column** by itself and a separate expression that can pull just the **Net** total column. I know both can be captured in one expression but I need to separate expressions capturing each column

My Regex For The **Description** Column:

```
^[A-Z\d]+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+(\w+)
```

*Here I'm only getting the first word of the Description. I need the full description without anything else.

My Regex For The **Net Column**:

```
^(\S+) .\d{2} \d
```

Sample Text:

```
2020-08-26 PILE OF LIFE HEALTH PRODUCTS LP Page 1 A/P Remittance Advice Direct Deposit 2020-08-26

Cheque # 11361 Vendor # 0828 HAIN CELESTIAL CANADA, ULC

Invoice #  Date       Description  Gross       Disc  Net
===============================================================

225299     2020-07-24 P2156678     7,610.52    .00   7,610.52 
225839     2020-07-22 P2157105     7,826.28    .00   7,826.28 
225969     2020-07-22 P2157106     8,760.59    .00   8,760.59 
226384     2020-07-22 P2157104     42,274.76   .00   42,274.76
CR01BEPJ   2020-08-17 MULTI MCBS   4,470.06-   .00   4,470.06-
CR01BEXS   2020-08-24 MULTI MCBS   5,212.81-   .00   5,212.81-

DM20082311 2020-08-14 LIFESTYLE MARKETS NA   201.25-   .00   201.25-
DM20083583 2020-08-17 KARDISH FOOD FRANCHI   281.37-   .00   281.37-
DM20085965 2020-08-12 AVRILSUPERMARCHE-WAR   871.50-   .00   871.50-
DM20086678 2020-08-12 AVRILSUPERMARCHE-WAR   871.50-   .00   871.50-
DM20089459 2020-07-30 LOBLAWS                8.90-     .00   8.90-  
DM20089500 2020-08-14 COUNTRY GROCER-CHASE   105.00-   .00   105.00-

========================================== 54,449.76 .00 54,449.76

Printed on 2020-08-26 at 6:26

2020-04-23 PILE OF LIFE HEALTH PRODUCTS LP Page 1 A/P Remittance Advice Direct Deposit 2020-04-23

Cheque # 9699 Vendor # 0828 HAIN CELESTIAL CANADA, ULC

Invoice # Date Description Gross Disc Net ===================================================================================

218124     2020-02-27 P2151168     2,253.44    .00   2,253.44 
219021     2020-03-18 P2152030     35,242.65   .00   35,242.65
219216     2020-03-18 P2152031     8,306.81    .00   8,306.81 
CR01BASW   2020-04-20 MULTI MCBS   5,278.05-   .00   5,278.05-

DM2004W450 2020-04-17 RETURNS WFM-GR-20589   124.63-   .00   124.63-
DM2004W828 2020-04-17 RETURNS WFM-GR-20589   266.09-   .00   266.09-
DM20042157 2020-04-07 AVRIL                  871.50-   .00   871.50-
DM20043798 2020-04-07 COUNTRY GROCER         105.00-   .00   105.00-
DM20043892 2020-04-07 COUNTRY GROCER         105.00-   .00   105.00-
DM20048663 2020-04-07 AVRIL                  871.50-   .00   871.50-
DM20049986 2020-04-02 LA MOISSON             258.69-   .00   258.69-

========================================== 37,922.44 .00 37,922.44

Printed on 2020-04-23 at 13:13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all the words in the first pattern, you could optionally repeat matching either a space or hyphen using a character class followed by 1+ word characters `(?:[ -]\w+)*` inside the capturing group.

```
^[A-Z\d]+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+(\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/koIykB/1)

---

For the `Net` column, you can extend the first pattern and match 1 or more non whitespace characters for a broad match

```
^[A-Z\d]+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7j5B7a/1)

Or a bit more specific for the Gross, Disc and Net columns matching a dot and 2 digits for Disc and matching the dot and comma for Gross and Net:

```
^[A-Z\d]+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*\s+\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}-?\s+\.\d{2}\s+(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}-?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i28EU8/1)

Comment: Your suggested Regex to match the first pattern is perfect; and both regex examples you provided for the gross worked fine on my submitted sample data. However when testing on another sample data seen below it did not bring in the gross? I think it has to do with the comma  and slash characters in the Description column. Will edit post with updated sample and try to give link. [link] (https://regex101.com/r/i28EU8/3)

Comment: I'm trying and getting closer to solving....just one line causing a problem now: [link](https://regex101.com/r/i28EU8/4)  This is the line: DM20084246 2020-08-25 WHOLE FOODS - EAST    126.68-   .00   126.68-

Comment: @DavidKameka Let me check...1 mom

Comment: @DavidKameka this will capture all the values values in group 1 for example https://regex101.com/r/rSDIVP/1 This part `.*?` will match as least as possible until the first occurrence of the numerical value with optional comma's and a dot followed by 2 decimal digits.

Comment: Or for example use a repeating group which will match `[,/ -]` followed by word characters https://regex101.com/r/BzKc8f/1

Comment: @DavidKameka Or perhaps it will be ok to lean on the 2 or more whitespace chars before the numerical value `^[A-Z\d]+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+[\w ,/-]+\s{2}\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/1AAT3q/1

Comment: it's working perfectly; but so I understand.... in this case \w+.*? is capturing on the Description Column. Your saying `*?` will grab everything... **including** **spaces** until it hits a number \d. So we could even have the opposite `\d+.*?\w` which would capture all numbers AND spaces until it hits a word character right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223662/discussion-between-david-kameka-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you (written in python (i dont's know .net)

```
items = [ '225299     2020-07-24 P2156678     7,610.52    .00   7,610.52',
         '226384     2020-07-22 P2157104     42,274.76   .00   42,274.76',
         'DM20082311 2020-08-14 LIFESTYLE MARKETS NA   201.25-   .00   201.25-' ,
         'CR01BEPJ   2020-08-17 MULTI MCBS   4,470.06-   .00   4,470.06-']
for item in items:
    print(list(filter(None,[x.strip(' ') for x in re.findall(r'\d\s([\w\s]+)\s\d',item)])))
```

**output**

```
['P2156678']
['P2157104']
['LIFESTYLE MARKETS NA']
['MULTI MCBS']
```